# Dovecot won't deliver the first mail to a mailstore on nfs share

Tags: nfs, dovecot, email-server, email

I'm building a mail platform using Dovecot/postfix/MySQL/iredmail/etc. The business end is on Ubuntu 13.04, the mailstore is an NFS share on Ubuntu 12.04.

Now when I try to send a mail to a new account, I get this in the postfix logs.

> Aug 29 12:39:23 core-01-mail postfix/pipe[8374]: 5BEFF7A1:
>   to=, relay=dovecot, delay=1009,
>   delays=706/0.37/0/302, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)

However, if I tell it to use a local directory as a mailstore it works fine. So far it looks like my NFS share is busted, except....

If I then change it back to using the NFS mailstore, it continues to work fine. It's only the first mail that isn't working.

I've turned on full verbose debug logging for dovecot, but I'm not seeing any errors or warnings.

incidentally, here's my nfs mount

```
172.1.1.15:/voldata  /data   nfs     nfsvers=3,hard,intr,auto 0 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much information. Can you access /data the normal way? and make directories / files there? Small guess:  shouldn't you mount with "rw" too? I don't think that is the problem however, as I think Postfix would have said "Cannot create directory" instead "Temporary failure". Can you post the output of "nfsstat" anyways?

Comment: that's the thing, it creates the directories, it delivers mail, just not that first mail. Also, this is actually gluster mounted using an nfs client. If I use a regular nfs share, that works perfectly. What I'm wondering is, what's dovecot doing differently with that first mail? I've actually dismantled the gluster so I can use nfs while I debug other bits, but I may try the nfsstat tomorrow